# Can Celery pass a Status Update to a non-Blocking Caller?

Tags: python, asynchronous, flask, celery

I am using [Celery](https://docs.celeryproject.org/en/latest/index.html) to asynchronously perform a group of operations. There are a lot of these operations and each may take a long time, so rather than send the results back in the return value of the Celery worker function, I'd like to send them back one at a time as custom state updates. That way the caller can implement a progress bar with a change state callback, and the return value of the worker function can be of constant size rather than linear in the number of operations.

Here is a simple example in which I use the Celery worker function `add_pairs_of_numbers` to add a list of pairs of numbers, sending back a custom status update for every added pair.

```
#!/usr/bin/env python

"""
Run worker with:

    celery -A tasks worker --loglevel=info
"""
from celery import Celery

app = Celery("tasks", broker="pyamqp://guest@localhost//", backend="rpc://")

@app.task(bind=True)
def add_pairs_of_numbers(self, pairs):
    for x, y in pairs:
        self.update_state(state="SUM", meta={"x":x, "y":y, "x+y":x+y})
    return len(pairs)

def handle_message(message):
    if message["status"] == "SUM":
        x = message["result"]["x"]
        y = message["result"]["y"]
        print(f"Message: {x} + {y} = {x+y}")

def non_looping(*pairs):
    task = add_pairs_of_numbers.delay(pairs)
    result = task.get(on_message=handle_message)
    print(result)

def looping(*pairs):
    task = add_pairs_of_numbers.delay(pairs)
    print(task)
    while True:
        pass

if __name__ == "__main__":
    import sys

    if sys.argv[1:] and sys.argv[1] == "looping":
        looping((3,4), (2,7), (5,5))
    else:
        non_looping((3,4), (2,7), (5,5))
```

If you run just `./tasks` it executes the `non_looping` function. This does the standard Celery thing: makes a delayed call to the worker function and then uses `get` to wait for the result. A `handle_message` callback function prints each message, and the number of pairs added is returned as the result. This is what I want.

```
$ ./task.py
Message: 3 + 4 = 7
Message: 2 + 7 = 9
Message: 5 + 5 = 10
3
```

Though the non-looping scenario is sufficient for this simple example, the real world task I'm trying to accomplish is processing a batch of files instead of adding pairs of numbers. Furthermore the client is a [Flask](https://www.fullstackpython.com/flask.html) REST API and therefore cannot contain any blocking `get` calls. In the script above I simulate this constraint with the `looping` function. This function starts the asynchronous Celery task, but does not wait for a response. (The infinite `while` loop that follows simulates the web server continuing to run and handle other requests.)

If you run the script with the argument "looping" it runs this code path. Here it immediately prints the Celery task ID then drops into the infinite loop.

```
$ ./tasks.py looping
a39c54d3-2946-4f4e-a465-4cc3adc6cbe5
```

The Celery worker logs show that the add operations are performed, but the caller doesn't define a callback function, so it never gets the results.

(I realize that this particular example is embarrassingly parallel, so I could use [chunks](https://docs.celeryproject.org/en/latest/userguide/canvas.html#chunks) to divide this up into multiple tasks. However, in my non-simplified real-world case I have tasks that cannot be parallelized.)

What I want is to be able to specify a callback in the `looping` scenario. Something like this.

```
def looping(*pairs):
    task = add_pairs_of_numbers.delay(pairs, callback=handle_message) # There is no such callback.
    print(task)
    while True:
        pass
```

In the Celery documentation and all the examples I can find online (for example [this](https://blog.miguelgrinberg.com/post/using-celery-with-flask)), there is no way to define a callback function as part of the `delay` call or its `apply_async` equivalent. You can only specify one as part of a `get` callback. That's making me think this is an intentional design decision.

In my REST API scenario I can work around this by having the Celery worker process send a "status update" back to the Flask server in the form of an HTTP post, but this seems weird because I'm starting to replicate messaging logic in HTTP that already exists in Celery.

Is there any way to write my `looping` scenario so that the caller receives callbacks without making a blocking call, or is that explicitly forbidden in Celery?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's a pattern that is not supported by celery although you can (somewhat) trick it out by posting custom state updates to your task [as described here](https://docs.celeryproject.org/en/latest/userguide/tasks.html#custom-states).

> Use update_state() to update a task’s state:.
>
> ````
> def upload_files(self, filenames):
>     for i, file in enumerate(filenames):
>         if not self.request.called_directly:
>             self.update_state(state='PROGRESS',
>                 meta={'current': i, 'total': len(filenames)})```
> ````

The reason that celery does not support such a pattern is that task producers (callers) are strongly decoupled from the task consumers (workers) with the only communications between the two being the broker to support communication from producers to consumers and the result backend supporting communications from consumers to producers.  The closest you can get currently is with polling a task state or writing a custom result backend that will allow you to post events either via AMP RPC or redis subscriptions.